# Sheets Script (Problems with send mail)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

Good afternoon, I'm trying to send an email and the code I wrote (basic) it sends email only separately for each line and I need it to send an email at once.

You can understand better if you visualize the code

```
 for(var i =4; i\<=sheet.getLastRow(); i++){

var inv = sheet.getRange(i,11).getValue();

if(inv<=100){
    var ref = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
        var name = sheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
    var qnty= sheet.getRange(i,9).getValue();
        var mailAddress = emailRange.getValue();

    var message = 'Work' + ref + name +  qnty ;
    var subject = 'Test';

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(i,13).setValue("Send"); 
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: No it didn't help to visualize the code.  You want to send only 1 email, or an email to each of the `emailAddress` that match your criteria `inv <= 100`?

Comment: What is `emailRange` and `emailAddress`, they are not defined in you code snippet?

Comment: thanks for trying to help.
Just an email address.
I have a column if the value is = or below 100 send a warning (email)

Comment: var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("INV");
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheets2").getRange("A1");

Comment: I guess I still don't understand the question.  Is it working at all?  Should `emailAddress` be `mailAddress`?

Comment: It is working, the only problem is that the emails go separate and I need all this data in the email to be sent at once.
Yes...My fault, (it's mailAddress) I already fixed the error.

Comment: So you do want to send only 1 email?  In that email is a list of all the items that match your criteria `inv <= 100`?

Comment: From what I've been seeing, I need to store the values in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

To send only 1 email with a list of the items that match the criteria `inv <= 100` append to a message string each item.

You are using getValue() for each row, I would suggest instead to get all the data using getValues() and then loop through the values array.

I would have used setValues() for "Send" but don't know what else is in that column.

**Script**

```
function test() {
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("INV");
  let emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheets2").getRange("A1");
  let mailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let message = "";
  let subject = 'Test';
  // i is row -1
  for( let i=3; i<sheet.getLastRow(); i++ ){

    let inv = values[i][10];
  
    if( inv <= 100 ){
      let ref = values[i][3];
      let name = values[i][4];
      let qnty= values[i][8];

      message = message+'Work' + ref + name +  qnty +"\n" ;
      // unfortunately can't do anything about this without knowing what is column N
      sheet.getRange(i+1,13).setValue("Send");
    }
  }
  if( message === "" ) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("No items found");
  }
  else {
    MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Google Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: The following error appears:
TypeError: values is not a function.
In relation to "Send" it is used in the columns when the email was sent.

Comment: Sorry my mistake see corrections about `(i,3)` becomes `[i][3]`,  same for others.